# Proving two sample t-statistic with pooled standard deviation

Tags: regression

I'm trying to prove that t = b1 / s(b1) is equal to the two sample t-statistic. But it was given from my supervisor that I should take very specific steps, so the first thing I've done was using the formula for beta one which is $$\beta_1 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X})(Y_i - \bar{Y})}{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2} $$

I've already shown that ${\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2} $ is $\frac{n_1 n_0} n $.

Now the next step is proving $\beta_1 = \bar{Y_1} - \bar{Y_0}$ using the answer from previous step above and $\bar{Y} = \frac{n_1 \bar{Y_1} + n_0 \bar{Y_0} } n  $.

So far I've done below steps

[image]

But I can't seem to progress further. Would there be another formula or approach to solving this problem?

Also noting that X is binary variable and Y is continuous.